# How do I span columns with a div-based table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like to have a cell go across two columns with two cells below it.  How do I do this in CSS with `<div>` elements? It should be equivalent to:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Major column</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C1</td>
    <td>C2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please note that C1 and C2 are not necessarily going to be 50% each. The value may change depending on their contents. I also need all items in those cells no matter how many rows there are to line up just like they would in a table.

Comment: Including the general structure of your `div`s might make the questions more understandable.

Comment: From your edit it almost sounds like you are trying to use divs for the sake of using divs. If your data is tabular, use a table.

Comment: Following up on @Joel's comment: Are you doing a page layout, or are you displaying tabular data? If your displaying tabular data, then that's what tables are built for -- no shame in using them. If you're doing layout, then it would be best to drop the table metaphor altogether and design it using embedded divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Please note that C1 and C2 are not
>   necessarily going to be 50% each. The
>   value may change depending on their
>   contents. I also need all items in
>   those cells no matter how many rows
>   there are to line up just like they
>   would in a table."

The above is not possible in a cross browser way, without using a table (You can simulate table layout with CSS: "display: table", but that doesn't work in IE6 or IE7).

I would suggest you think a bit differently when designing with CSS instead of tables, it's not possible to just replace "tr" and "td" with "div" and make things magically work like they used to. I suggest you set the widths of the bottom "cells", and use one of the options people have given you above.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

You would want markup like:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="topRow">Major column</div>
    <div class="leftCol">C1</div>
    <div class="rightCol">C2</div>
<div>
```

And then some css to position them:

```
div.topRow {
  width:100%;
  clear:both;
}
div.leftCol {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
div.rightCol {
  width:50%;
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: +1 But you don't have to specify the width and clear on topRow

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend putting them in a container div if being used for layout.

HTML:

```
<div> full width </div>
<div class="column50"> left </div>
<div class="column50"> right </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.column50 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

In case it's unclear, there's no need to create two separate CSS classes for this case. Both of the last two divs have a 50% width, no margin, and no padding.  Setting them both to 50% width and left float has the same effect as setting the right one with a right float instead.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above will work, but keep in mind that  elements will "escape" from their parent div in IE6. This is a pain, but IE6 support is still something most people need to think about.

The solution to escaping is to give the containing element a height or width (any  will do, it will stretch to fit so usually 1% is what I use.).

Also, if setting widths, keep in mind that any borders or margin you set are *in addition to* the width of the elements, so if you set two divs at 50% with a border or margin, you will get a line break.